# Symfony remove page parameter

Tags: symfony, knppaginator

I'm using knp_paginator on symfony to list the information.
The information I'm listing generate lots of pages.
The problem is when I filter my results.

Let's say I'm on page 3 the generated link is `https://something.com/blabla?page=3`
but since my filter doesn't generate 3 pages I get 0 results. If I change page on the URL i can see the filtered results. How can I make the page parameter disapear when I apply the filters with the controller?

Comment: Show me your code. You can point default result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think answer for your question showed in an example of official docs:

```
  $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $query, /* query NOT result */
        $request->query->getInt('page', 1)/*page number*/,
        10/*limit per page*/
    );

    // parameters to template
    return $this->render('AcmeMainBundle:Article:list.html.twig', array('pagination' => $pagination));
```

In this example the default parameter will be first page with 10 max per page. If count records less than 10 it'll show 1 page with 7 records.